# I need 1:1 help with some Apex code coverage issues, how to ask?

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I want to respect the community here so I'd love your feedback on the best way to go about this:
I inherited an org with some code coverage issues. I'm a beginner developer at best and trying to work through the code myself and figure out how to bring it in line has been a challenge.

**Is there a place where I can go request 1:1 help for things like this (for an appropriate fee, of course)?**

Is it OK to just post a big angry block of code in here and ask for you all to tear into it?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you may have on the best way I can get this code reviewed, revised and (hopefully) learn something on the way there!

Comment: You can hire a developer on the AppExchange by posting in a section there. Commercial ads aren't accepted here.

Comment: Great, thank you @crmprogdev! I just know it's probably too involved for a community post but I wasn't sure where to turn!

Comment: You're quite welcome. I'm confident you'll find devs looking for work by posting there

Comment: If you do hire a developer to work with you, the old advice of "you get what you pay for" goes a long way here. It is really easy to write bad code, and I have seen some SFDC partners that write some pretty horrendous stuff. You want to make the system you inherited better, not add to the mess.

Answer (score 0):

**Posting a big block of code without specific issue relates questions about it is not something we want to encourage here.** We'd prefer you try to learn it, and come to us with specific question in learning, or specific question in dealing with issues (eg: how to technically test this complex code construct, I've tried this and that approach but neither are good).

One-on-One sessions are definitely a good way to learn and get help, but there are also hard to get. That doesn't mean there aren't people who'll help you for free though. You could try:

- [Our chat channel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)
- Hire a partner or freelancer. To review or teach you how to review. Look for someone Advanced Developer certified, at least. Though that's still no grantee. It's easy to write code on force.com, it's harder to write good code.
- Some Salesforce or community events will have "Ask an expert" sessions, where you can come with questions or bring your code. I think this has been done at [dreamforce](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF15/) but i'm not sure if it gets done every year. Even if not, there are 100 reasons to attend dreamforce anyway!
- Premier support, while I don't think they officially offer this, you could still try to do it as developer support.
- Take training and do it yourself. Salesforce has online instructor lead advanced developer courses, which should teach you the basic skills to do some test reviewing.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a beginner SF dev too but I think I can help you out. If I can find a way to message you, I can teach you during my free time with what I know. No fees necessary

Comment: This should probably be a comment?

Comment: sorry i don't have enough rep to comment but i would still like to offer some help